# Why doesn't my ListView refresh after adding new data to Firebase?

Tags: android, listview, firebase

I'm having trouble reloading the `ListView` after pushing a string to firebase. `ListView` updates when I restart the application. I have used the `notifyDataSetChanged()` function with my `ListAdapter`. Here is what I'm doing:

```
myFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("App",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            names = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();



            String[] planets = new String[] { names, "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
                    "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
            ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
            namesList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

            // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.
            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, namesList);

            mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase engineer here,

I would recommend checking out a [simple chat example](https://github.com/mcdonamp/RoseAndroidChat/tree/master/AndroidChatSlides/app/src/main/java/com/google/mpmcdonald/androidchatslides) I made recently (what you're trying to do is detailed [here](https://github.com/mcdonamp/RoseAndroidChat/blob/master/AndroidChatSlides/app/src/main/java/com/google/mpmcdonald/androidchatslides/MainActivity.java#L39-L52)) or our more fully fleshed out [Android Chat example](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/androidchat), which both demonstrate how to use model objects to bind to ArrayAdapters and ListViews.

The TL;DR is that you want to do something more like this:

```
// Create instance variables to be used from inside your activity
private ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> mMessages;
private Firebase mRef;

...

// Some time later, instantiate your instance variables
this.mMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();

// Set up ListAdapter
ListAdapter messageAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this , R.layout.message_layout , mMessages);
this.setListAdapter(messageAdapter);

// Set up Firebase
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
this.mRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");

// Add listener to your Firebase database reference
this.mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        // Create objects and add to ArrayList, which should fire ArrayAdapter methods and update the ListView
        Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
        MainActivity.this.mMessages.add(data);
    }

    ...
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are creating new listadapter. Just use the old one. There's a conflict here because you are creating a new adapter and setting it to the same time you are calling notifyDatachanged. It is not logical. Do not bind new adapter.

Comment: the problem is I cannot create new listAdapter outside the onDataChanged function scope because outside that function namesList is not accessible, it shows empty. :(

Comment: change namesList to final variable if this method is global. If not, change namesList to global variable. does it work ?

Comment: sorry i guess i understood you wrong. you have already access to namesList. :s

Comment: just remove new adapter. add variables to namesList and call notifyDatachanged.

Comment: I have moved the listAdapter outside the onDataChanged() function(Where new adapter is not created every time). It displays the newly added value after the app is restarted. i.e problem still the same. :\

Comment: hmm interesting. normally logic is this: just create one adapter and set it to view. Just change values of list connected to adapter. Then call notifydatachanged. This logic should work

Comment: @user14570 if you could just write the code of what you;re saying then that would be great... :)

Comment: haha :) i am happy for you it works.knowing strategy but struggling in codes are best way to learn i guess :)